# increment if not same value of column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

i want to increment order if rank value is not same

i have tried following query

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9a7d/2)

```
select rank, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS `myorder`
from myRankorder, (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS a
order by rank desc
```

but it return this result

```
RANK   MYORDER
10     1
8      2
6      3
6      4
4      5
4      6
4      7
3      8
2      9
1      10
```

Desired Output

```
RANK   MYORDER
10     1
8      2
6      3
6      3
4      4    <-- if rank value is same do not increment myorder value
4      4
4      4
3      5
2      6
1      7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit more complicated.  You need an additional variable:

```
select rank,
       if (@prevrank = rank, @rownum, @rownum := @rownum + 1) AS `myorder`,
       @prevrank := rank
from myRankorder cross join
     (SELECT @rownum := 0, @prevrank := -1) const
order by rank desc;
```

Just one point.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select`.  In practice this works, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks, I will check your query

Comment: i have modified your query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9a7d/6 please check just one row value doesn't have desired result

Comment: @PragneshChauhan . . . Your SQL Fiddle had a mistake in it.  The third column is `@prevrank := rank`.

Comment: can you please check this question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55168/increment-row-value-does-not-work-properly-with-where-condition